# How to make Apache pass on some URLs to a different server

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have copied most of a php website to my local computer for debugging and development. There is a HUGE number of images on the original remote website that I cannot transfer. The same images are served by two different domain names on the same server so I want to get going by mapping `first_domain.com` to `127.0.0.1` in `/etc/hosts` and configure Apache (latest, greatest version) to pull the `/images/*/*` from `second_domain.com/images/*/*`

Configuring `/etc/hosts` was easy. But I do not know what I am doing wrong in configuring Apache.

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
#...
# Configure mod_proxy_html to understand HTML4/XHTML1
<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>
```

In `conf/extra/proxy-html.conf`, in addition to defaults:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /properties/ http://newhawaiiproperties.com/properties/
<Location /properties/>
    ProxyPassReverse /
    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://newhawaiiproperties.com/properties/ /properties/
    ProxyHTMLURLMap / /properties/
</Location>
```

Should I change `ProxyRequests Off` to `ProxyRequests On`?

**update:** I am realizing I do not need to change the HTML files, they are all jpgs so I should be able to get rid of `ProxyHTML...` stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was overthinking/overconfiguring it it. The following worked.

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

ProxyPass /foo http://second_domain.com/foo
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://second_domain.com/foo
```

No wildcards or freaking rewriting needed! It sends everything like `/foo/bar/x.jpg` to `http://second_domain.com/foo/bar/x.jpg`